# Grafana / graphite - maxSeries on #A and #B

Tags: statistics, graphite, grafana, statsd

I've got 2 price metrics in Grafana (datasource: Graphite) showing prices of `something` in 2 different currencies `EUR` and `PLN`. I would like to display `maxSeries` of those 2 metrics, however before comparing them makes sense I need to convert currencies to the common one. I am using the currency exchange metric to `divideSeries` the `PLN` metric, converting it to `EUR`.

My problem is that I can't use `maxSeries` with 2 arguments, like `maxSeries(#A,#C)` in a same way as you can pass `#B` as an argument to `divideSeries`. It simply does not work correctly.

My metrics:

```
#A - stats.gauges.something.EUR.price.removeAbovePercentile(5)
#B - stats.gauges.currency.EURPLN
#C - stats.gauges.something.PLN.price.divideSeries(#B)
#D - maxSeries(#A,#C)        <---- desired output
```

When I use the `maxSeries` on wildcard query listing multiple metrics e.g.: `stats.gauges.*.EUR.price.maxSeries()` it works ok. In my example I need to do some transformations first, so I can't simply use wildcard.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the `Toggle Edit Mode` and manually typed: `maxSeries(#A,#C)`, but the output was incorrect, the blue line should be max, but it wasn't always max for some reason.
[image: grafana maxSeries]

I had to remove the `removeAbovePercentile(5)` function from `#A` first.